Error: VM option 'UseG1GC' is experimentError: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.Error:A fatal exception has occurred.Programwillexit
i am getting this error while starting the zookeeper server
on macOs terminal.
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
I've checked the config file of zookeeper there is no such option for JVM is avaliable.

You won't find it in the properties... It's part of zookeeper-server-start.sh file

Which version of the JVM is this on?

./zkServer.sh [--config ] {start|start-foreground|stop|version|restart|status|print-cmd} this is the command that should be executed to start ZK. The --config takes the directory where the zookeeper.properties is present (not the path of the properties file). Give it a shot and check.
